# Cannot install Windows Shell Integration of Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools

Tags: integration, windows-shell, windows-explorer, tfs-power-tools

When trying to install [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f), if I select `Windows Shell Integration`, I will get the error message that stops me from moving on.

What should I do to get rid of this error?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel - Uninstall Program and enter "Team Foundation" in search  box and remove all related Power Tools ones.

Reinstall the tool.

[image]